# how add method of list interface works when there is no body for it? where is the add method of list interface defined?

Tags: java

As we know methods in interface don't have bodies...then how come methods of list, set, sortedset, navigable set work without body.. Please explain? looks like simple question but I am not able to give it a thought?

Answer (score 0):

Interface defines the *contract* which must be followed by the classes implementing the interface.

Interface is Abstraction. We define the method (function) signatures in Interface. `java.util.List` is an interface. `java.util.ArrayList` is a concrete class implementing the interface `List`. The method implementation are present in `ArrayList`. Similarly `LinkedList` is another concrete Implementation of `List`.

User code works with object, object are of one of the concrete implementation. We can not have an object of an interface. There may be a class where you only see fields ( variables ) of type `List` are present. But in such a case there must be some mechanism which would *inject* concrete implementation to such fields.

Methods of Interface  can not work until unless some class provides concrete implementation. We can refer the objects of concrete implementation using a reference variable defined of type Interface. Like

`List<String> listObj = new ArrayList<>();`

Now whenever we call `listObj.add("alpha");` then it is actually the method defined by concrete implementation (in this case ArrayList) which is executed. Note that above we have used direct assignment for `listObj`, in actual code this may happen in constructor or setter method.